# Export entire library depend on env

Tags: javascript, import, export

Imagine I have some library called `shared` , shared have a lot of files inside , I want to divide this library on 2 different builds `shared/es` , `shared/node` . First one for browser use , second one for `node` use , and depend on enviroment I want to export different folder, lets see some example :

**shared/index.js**

```
if (process.env.SERVER) {require('shared/es')}
else {require('shared/node`)}
```

and then I want to have opportunity to make exports from this `shared/index.js` file same I way as if I would make it from `shared/es`, I mean , imagine in root I have `index.js` file, and I want to import from `shared` some code

**index.js**

```
 import {isEmpty} from 'shared/utils/lodashAlternative'
```

and it will mean the same as `shared/es/utils/lodashAlternative` or `shared/node/utils/lodashAlternative` . Is it possible to make somehow ?

Comment: Dynamic inports should do what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: could you pls attach example ? I need to import it in one place , and then reuse it, I need import and then export entile library , and I described above

Comment: or maybe it is possible to make on level of webpack to look on shared ans to shared/es or shared /node depend on enviroment , don't know how to solve it , my library have es6 syntax , which needed for tree shaking (import/export) , and I have webpack build , which have ssr node env , and node doesn't work with es modules , I don't want to created a wheel , and run it wil (node -r esm file ), or anything like this , just want it to work properly

Comment: const main = document.querySelector("main");
for (const link of document.querySelectorAll("nav > a")) {
  link.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    import('/modules/my-module.js')
      .then(module => {
        module.loadPageInto(main);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        main.textContent = err.message;
      });
  });
}